# Basic git-plus configuration for Atom on macOS

Tags: git, macos, atom-editor

Before I begin, I have seen this thread: [Atom git-plus difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108733/atom-git-plus-difficulties)

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to ask the author for clarification about the precise issue I need help with (although I believe that isn't the purpose of comments anyway?).

---

I would like to configure Atom to connect to my GitHub repositories. I have installed the git-plus package and went through the process of creating an SSH key on my Mac and adding my public key to my GitHub account. I am pretty new to this stuff so I am confused by what may simple issues for more experienced people. I'd appreciate some help!

### Issue 1: Pointing git-plus to my local repositories

I have GitHub Desktop installed on my Mac and it is connected to my repositories online. git-plus has a setting for the "Git Path" but I'm really not sure where that is on my Mac. Is it the folder for my local repositories (that are synced through GitHub Desktop) or something else?

### Issue 2: Editing gitconfig

The git-plus instructions include this:

> Make sure your gitconfig file is configured. You must configure at least the user.email and user.name variables.

I don't have a clue where to find my `gitconfig` file. Again, this is probably pretty obvious, just not to me. Please could someone point me to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Git Path

This is where the `git` command is located on your system. By default it is simply "git" and Atom assumes it will find git in some expected place, such as `/usr/bin`. If your git is in an unusual place, simply put the path to git here. Even if it's in a usual place, you can put the path here; it won't hurt anything.

The easiest way to find the path to git is by typing `which git` into a terminal window.

### Gitconfig

Your gitconfig file is in your home directory, named `.gitconfig`. So, something like this for me:

```
/Users/dan/.gitconfig
```

You can configure the two mentioned values like this:

```
git config --global user.name John Doe
git config --global user.email j.doe@gmail.com
```

The gitconfig file can contain many more settings. You can find references to many of them on the [git-config documentation page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: Thanks for your response, Dan.